# Shortcode not picking up custom field

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, timthumb

I created a custom field that allows me to set the cropping style of timthumb, but I am also using short code to populate a page with blog posts, but the shortcode isn't picking up the customfield, so all the images look different.

Here is the code from index.php

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $thumb; ?>&h=150&w=600&zc=1&q=100&a=<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbcrop', true); ?>" 
       alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
</a>
```

Here is the code from blog.php (shortcode)

```
<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">
  <img src="'. get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumb.'&h=100&w=600&zc=1&q=100" 
       alt="'.get_the_title().'" />
</a>
```

The shortcode file hasn't been updated, as I'm not sure how to pass the customfield value.

Can anyone help out. Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your questions. In the first codesample, you add a GET parameter `a` with the shortcode's vaule to the image URL. You don't do so in the second. So why are you surprised you get a differeny effect? Note that you can use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`. The former definitely works during shortcode evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

could be a question of string concatenation - try (untested):

```
<a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'"><img src="'. get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/timthumb.php?src='.$thumb.'&h=100&w=600&zc=1&q=100&a='.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbcrop', true).'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" /></a>
```